# Mysql Query Get 3 Names From 3 IDS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this setup:

table members

```
id_member name  
---------------
```

table teams

```
id_team   id_leader   id_member1   id_member2
---------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to show in a html table these fields for all the teams :
id_team, leader name, name of member1, name of member2

Tried several queries with multiple selects but there were problems when one member was in more then one team, wrong results (all the combinations)  were shown

Example of what I want:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/ao9oxi.jpg

Comment: Please provide your sample data, desired result and what you have done so far.

Comment: I provided in description a picture example of what I want

Comment: What happens when you want three members? Consider using a TeamMembership table

Comment: Hello, you are right about that because it is flexible, but in my situation the number is fixed in the requirements just 3 (and have 3 dropdown in the interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using join query as below

```
select TEAM.id_team, LEADER.name, MEMBER1.name, MEMBER2.name 
from teams as TEAM 
join members as LEADER on(LEADER.id_member=TEAM.id_leader) 
join members as MEMBER1 on(MEMBER1.id_member=TEAM.id_member1) 
join members as MEMBER2 on(MEMBER2.id_member=TEAM.id_member2)
```